# Can't save screen resolution setting

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, resolution

My screen resolution in windows and previous version of Ubuntu (9.04) was 1152 x 864.

But in Ubuntu 10.04 it gives me an option of 1024 x 786 and 1360 x 786.

I have some how managed to add 1152x684 resolution by using xrandr command.

> searock@searock-desktop:~$ cvt 1152
>   864
>  1152x864 59.96 Hz (CVT
>   1.00M3) hsync: 53.78 kHz; pclk: 81.75 MHz Modeline "1152x864_60.00" 81.75
>   1152 1216 1336 1520 864 867 871 897
>   -hsync +vsync
>  searock@searock-desktop:~$ xrandr
>   --newmode "1152x864_60.00" 81.75 1152 1216 1336 1520 864 867 871 897 -hsync
>   +vsync
>  searock@searock-desktop:~$ xrandr
>   --addmode S-video 1152x864
>  xrandr: cannot find output
>   "S-video"
>   searock@searock-desktop:~$ xrandr
>   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current
>   1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
>   VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal
>   left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm
>   x 0mm
>  1360x768 59.8
>  1024x768
>   60.0*
>  800x600 60.3 56.2
>  848x480 60.0
>  640x480 59.9
>   59.9
>  1152x864_60.00 (0x124) 81.0MHz
>  h: width 1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew 0 clock
>   53.3KHz
>  v: height 864 start 867 end 871 total 897 clock
>   59.4Hz
>  searock@searock-desktop:~$ xrandr
>   --addmode VGA1 1152x864_60.00

But the problem is when ever I restart my computer I get this message.

**Could not apply the stored configuration for the monitors. Could not find a suitable configuration of screens.**

[image]

And then it comes back to 1024 x 786

My graphic card details : [Intel(R) 82945G Express Chipset Family](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/graphics/intel945g).

Is there any way I can fix this once for all ?

Thanks.

**Edit 1 :** [rumtscho](https://superuser.com/users/32293/rumtscho) has suggested me to modify xorg.conf file. But I am not sure what HorizSync means? is it Horizontal frequency ?

My monitor model is [Acer v173](http://us.acer.com/acer/product.do;jsessionid=7BA2FBD94B14407926B149A5ED584838.public_a_us003?LanguageISOCtxParam=en&rcond5e.c2att92=453&inu49e.current.c2att92=453&link=ln314e&CountryISOCtxParam=US&kcond47e.c2att92=453&rcond159e.att21k=1&kcond48e.c2att101=36126&rcond190e.att21k=1&acond23=US&rcond4e.att21k=1&sp=page17e&rcond157e.c2att92=453&ctx1g.c2att92=453&rcond42e.att21k=1&kcond50e.c2att92=453&rcond45e.att21k=1&rcond158e.c2att1=25&ctx2.c2att1=25&inu53e.current.c2att92=453&rcond3).

Here's my specification.

[image]

So what should be HorizSync and VertRefresh ?

**Edit 2 :**

I have edited my Xorg.conf file as follows :

> Section "Monitor"
>   Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
>   HorizSync 30-80
>   VertRefresh 55-75
>   EndSection

then I added the resolution and restarted my computer and still I am facing the same problem.

Is there something that I am missing?

**Edit 3 :** For now I have  edited /etc/gdm/Init/Default(gdm startup scripts) to include following xrandr commands, just below line **initctl -q emit login-session-start DISPLAY_MANAGER=gdm**

```
xrandr --newmode "1152x864_60.00" 81.75 1152 1216 1336 1520 864 867 871 897 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1152x864_60.00<br/>
xrandr -s  1152x864_60.00
```

This has solved my problem, but this commands have increased my computer's boot time.

I think I will have to edit xorg file properly.

**Edit 4 :** Instead of adding this files to gdm startup scripts I have created a shell script and added it to startup (System -> Preference -> Startup Applications)

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1152x864_60.00" 81.75 1152 1216 1336 1520 864 867 871 897 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1152x864_60.00
xrandr -s  1152x864_60.00
```

And don't forget to add execution rights. (Right Click -> Properties -> Permission -> Allow executing file as program)

Comment: It might be easier, too, if you turn off extra graphics effects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure because you've got Intel graphics, but it sounds like the good old trouble with bad EDID. In a nutshell, your monitor sends bad info to your graphic card, it cannot read the maximal frequencies and errs on the side of caution, using the lowest possible settings only.

randr is (by design!) only meant for run-time changes. For any permanent configuration, you need to change your X server settings. For this, edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf (This is an important system file! Make a backup first!). You need to add HorizSync and VertRefresh lines. The result should look like this:

```
Section "Monitor"
Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
HorizSync 30-35
VertRefresh 55-75
EndSection
```

Warning: Do not use the numbers I posted here! If you set a frequency in HorizSync which is too high, it might permanently damage your monitor. They fluctuate considerably between monitor models, I've seen them anywhere between 30 Hz and 75 Hz. You should look up the correct values in the monitor's user guide, or call the manufacturer's tech support and ask about vertical and horizontal frequency at your preferred resolution.

Maybe you'll need to add the mode line to the Xorg.conf manually (I forgot which section, I think Screen) but probably after the X restart you'll be able to set the resolution using the built-in graphical tool.

Even if this doesn't solve your problem, the xorg.conf is the place to save permanent changes to your screen configuration.

---

Edit, as an answer to your comments.

The HorizSync is the frequency, yes. On a nVidia card, setting the HorizSync and VertRefresh in the xorg.conf (then restarting X or just rebooting) makes all the usual resolutions available in the nVidia driver GUI. So choosing your preferred resolution there should be possible.

If this doesn't happen with the Intel drivers, you can manually add the resolution you want into your Xorg.conf. Still in the Monitor section, paste your modeline (which worked with xRandR). Then list the mode name as the Preferred mode option. Then, in the Screen section, Display subsection, add a Modes line, including the name of your mode.

The result should be something like this:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 30-80
    VertRefresh 55-75
    Modeline        "1152x864_60.00" 81.75 1152 1216 1336 1520 864 867 871 897 -hsync +vsync 
    Option          "PreferredMode" "1152x864_60.00"
EndSection
```

and below that, **within** the Screen section

```
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth           24
        Modes   "1152x864" "1024x768" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
```

I am not sure if you need the Display subsection, but I have found it in an old config file of mine. If it doesn't work, comment it out again. Cannot test it on my current system because I cannot restart just now, and my current monitor configuration is different. So it may still need some tweaking. But in theory, adding the modeline into Xorg.conf is the permanent version of adding it dynamically to RandR.

If you need to tweak, a good information source would be the Xorg.conf manual. http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html

If all else fails, I think there is a X profile file where you can add xRandR commands. It is certainly not elegant, and possibly as slow as your init script solution. Besides, I don't remember much about this file and how to use it, so cannot help you there.

And if these things fail too, maybe the problem is something else. As it is probably still X related, you could look into your /var/log/xorg.0.log file. If there are lines starting with (WW) or (EE), google these lines and you'll almost certainly find a solution.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean my HorizSync is it Horizontal frequency which is 30 ~ 80KHz? and how do I enter it? Is it like 30-80 ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have posted my monitor specification, can you help me with HorizSync? Please.

Comment: I have tried editing the xorg.conf file but it still doesn't work.